# Is it possible to deploy a HA mail server using juju?

Tags: juju

I'm looking for a way to easily deploy a highly available e-mail server using juju. Does anyone accomplished that already? Are there charms available for this?

Thank you

Comment: Not currently no, we should have this though, I filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/charms/+source/postfix/+bug/1291528